# How to play a movie on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

So I created a view that has a button in it that will play the movie.

Here is the action for that button:

```
- (IBAction)playMovie {

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"sample_iPod" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
}
```

However when I test the App and try to play the video the screen stays blank and in the log it shows this:

[Switching to process 9333 thread 0x13c03]

Any Idea what's up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the bounds of the player, and add the player's view to self.view:

```
 [theMovie.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
 [self.view addSubview: theMovie.view];
```

Comment: where is myView initialized? I'm getting "use of undeclared identifier, myView" I tried the class name of the .m file but that didn't work either.

Comment: sorry, quick cut 'n paste error.  You need to add theMovie view to the view of whatever view controller you're in, namely `self.view`

Comment: That kind of works except for the Controls for the video don't work, so they can't click done on the video and go back to the previous screen.  Any idea how to get that to work?

Comment: Hmmm, your original post was about getting the view to show up, which is now happening.  I will make one suggestion here, but if it doesn't work, please accept this answer and open a new question.  Try changing the scalingMode to MPMovieScalingModeNone;